# При выводе кода появляется ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу помочь. На экран должно выводится либо `Zabud pro stypendiiu`,либо `Zvychaina`, либо `Pidvyshchena`, но ничего из перечисленного не происходит.
Задача: код должен определять, какого уровня должна быть стипендия, смотря на оценки ("**Zvychaina**" - обычная стипендия,"**Pidvyshchena**" - Повышенная)

````
a=[]
a=int(input())
if int(n) >=1 and int(n)<=7:
    for i in a:
        if int(i) < 51:
            print("Zabud pro stypendiiu")
            break
        elif int(i) <90 and int(i) >50 :
             print("Zvychaina")
             break
        elif int(i) >=90:
            print("Pidvyshchena")
            break```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in a:
```

так это не работает, надо писать

```
for i in range(a):
```

вообще странный код с кучей лишних действий, можно было бы его и в такой превратить тогда:

```
a = int(input())
if int(n) >= 1 and int(n) <= 7:
    if a < 51:
        print("Zabud pro stypendiiu")
    elif a < 90 and a > 50:
        print("Zvychaina")
    elif a >=90:
        print("Pidvyshchena")
```

Если же вы вводите несколько значений (на что указывает `a=[]` и последующий цикл, то вы неправильно получаете список), можно было бы сделать так:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))

if int(n) >= 1 and int(n) <= 7:
    for i in a:
        if i < 51:
            print("Zabud pro stypendiiu")
        elif i < 90 and i > 50:
            print("Zvychaina")
        elif i >= 90:
            print("Pidvyshchena")
```

Кстати такие конструкции:

```
i < 90 and i > 50:
```

питон позволяет писать более компактно:

```
50 < i < 90
```

P.S.

и непонятно в вашем коде, что такое `n`:

```
int(n) >= 1 and int(n) <= 7:
```

Answer (score 0):

Такого результата можно добиться с помощью более простого способа:

```
while True:
    mark = input("Введите вашу оценку:\nА - 5 \nБ - от 3 до 4 \nВ - 2 \n[Оценка]: ")
    if mark == "А":
        print("Вам полагается повышенная стипендия \n")
        break
    elif mark == "Б":
        print("Вам полагается обычная стипендия \n")
        break
    elif mark == "В":
        print("Вам не полагается стипендия \n")
        break
    else:
        print("К сожалению, оценка не распознана \n"))
```